# Joint probability proof

Tags: probability

Question: A water management company provides the water required for hand basins in a public rest room. They have decided that the number of people using the hand basin every hour follows a Poisson distribution with a mean lambda , and a person's water usage is Normally distributed with a mean *"u"* and is independent of other people's water usage. Prove that the average total amount of water used per hour in this model will be *u* * *lambda*. TIA.

Comment: A normal random variable can take on negative values too. So unless the standard deviation is much smaller than the mean, normal distribution is not a good model for water usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda)$ be the number of people in an hour.
Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be independent normal random variables with mean $u$.

\begin{align}
E[\text{total amount of water used in hour}]
&= E[X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_N]
\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty E[X_1 + \cdots + X_N \mid N=n] P(N=n)
\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (E[X_1] + \cdots + E[X_n]) P(N=n)\\
&= \cdots
\end{align}